# Alamofire 5 AF.upload() fails to send an image to a server with an invalid certificate

Tags: ios, swift, certificate, alamofire

I am sending an image, using the following call:

```
AF.upload(...)
```

to a "Development server" that has an invalid certificate, and consequently, I get the following error:

```
NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be ...
```

I have already solved this problem for "AF.request(...)" calls; that is, I can perform "AF.request(...)" calls to a server with an invalid certificate using the following code:

```
#if DEBUGDEV

    //To enable connections with wrong certificate
    private let session: Session = {
        let evaluators: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [
        "api.my.server.dev.api.group.com": DisabledEvaluator()
        ]

        let manager = ServerTrustManager(allHostsMustBeEvaluated: false,
                                         evaluators: evaluators)
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default

        return Session(configuration: configuration,
                       serverTrustManager: manager,
                       eventMonitors: [ AlamofireLogger() ])
    }()
#else
    private let session: Session = Session.default
#endif
```

And then calling:

```
let request = self.session.request(urlConvertible)
```

In addition I have modified the Info.plist file to contain "NSAppTransportSecurity -> NSExceptionDomains -> "api.my.server.dev.api.group.com" -> "NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = false" and other entries that can be found in other StackOverFlow" posts.

However; the previous code works for "AF.request(...)", but not for "AF.upload(...)", so I would need a way to make "AF.upload(..)" work properly for servers with and invalid certificate.

Is it a way to "insert" the "Session" inside the "AF.upload(...)" call ? or
Is another way so that "AF.upload(...)" can connect to servers with an invalid certificate?

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing and updating my question, I have realised that the answer is easy; that is, in the same way I do not call
    AF.request(...)
but
    self.session.request(...)

I can do the same with upload; that is, to call:

```
self.session.upload(...)
```

instead of calling:

```
AF.upload(...)
```